# Add external script to functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble adding an external script to my functions.php. It has checks to see if there's an ACF field checked and if that's on a certain template.

This is the script I'm trying to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js?ver=1.8.52" async="async" id="vidyard-v4-js"> </script>`

Not seeing any errors loading it so I don't think II'm registering it correctly. Thanks

```
function add_vidyard_script(){
if (get_field('vidyard_video') && (is_page_template('templates-page/customers.php'))) {
        wp_get_script_tag(
            array(
                'id'        => 'vidyard-v4-js',
                'async' => true,
                'src'       => esc_url( 'https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js?ver=1.8.52' ),
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script('wp_get_script_tag');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_vidyard', 'add_vidyard_script');
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_vidyard` - that isn't a registered action in WP. Try changing that to `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The hook you want to use is `wp_enqueue_scripts` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/).
2. You should put the `add_action` inside of an if statement, to not run it unnecessary.
3. If you are using a "True / False" field from ACF, you need to check if it exists and what value it has. True is 1, false is 0.

So your code can look like

```
function add_vidyard_script(){
   wp_enqueue_script( 'vidyard-v4-js', 'https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js?ver=1.8.52' );
}


if ( ( get_field('vidyard_video') && get_field('vidyard_video') == 1 ) && (is_page_template('templates-page/customers.php')) ):
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_vidyard_script'); 
endif;
```

**Additional information:**

Using `wp_enqueue_scripts` you can use parameters.

First Parameter is the ID. Second is the URL. Third can be a dependency. Fourth can be a version number. Fifth can be a boolean to load the script in the footer.

So if you have a script with the id of "myscript", url of "https://script.js", it only works with "jquery", has  the version number of "1.0" and should be loaded in the footer instead of the header:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', 'https://script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

If you want to load it async, you will need to add a filter `script_loader_tag` to change the script tag and add the async attribute.

```
// add async attribute to enqueued script
function my_script_loader_tag($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if ($handle === 'myscript') { // id of your script defined in wp_enqueue_script 
        if (false === stripos($tag, 'async')) {
            $tag = str_replace(' src', ' async="async" src', $tag);
        }
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'my_script_loader_tag', 10, 3);
```

That's it, just a little filter.

---

Putting all together, your code can look like:

```
function add_vidyard_script(){
   wp_enqueue_script( 'vidyard-v4-js', 'https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js?ver=1.8.52' );
}

// add async attribute to enqueued script
function my_script_loader_tag($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if ($handle === 'vidyard-v4-js') { 
        if (false === stripos($tag, 'async')) {
            $tag = str_replace(' src', ' async="async" src', $tag);
        }
    }
    return $tag;
}


if ( ( get_field('vidyard_video') && get_field('vidyard_video') == 1 ) && (is_page_template('templates-page/customers.php')) ):
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_vidyard_script'); 
    add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'my_script_loader_tag', 10, 3);
endif;
```

Hope this also gives you a better understanding of using actions and filter in wordpress.

Comment: Howdo you add the async and the ID?

Comment: I edited my answer with additional script to add a async attribute to the script tag. Hope it helps you out!